# Difference between delegate {} and (input parameters) => {}

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I have a few methods like this

```
public void DoSomething(Action<int> action) { ... }
```

In some cases I do not use the parameters passed into action. Are there any differences I should be aware of between calling it like this

```
DoSomething(delegate { ... });
```

or

```
DoSomething(_ => { ... });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're equivalent. Personally I prefer `delegate {}` as it's obvious that you don't care about the parameters (to the extent of not even naming them), and you don't need to adapt the code based on the delegate signature - but both are fine.

Comment: Personally, I prefer not to use them, as you get clowns thinking they can be a substitute for lambda expressions, which will cause you a tonne of grief when dealing with `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too prefer the delegate syntax in this case. As you said, it makes it clear that you don't care about the parameters.